# Pseudo-streaming mp4 files does not work with flash player

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, pseudo-streaming

I've got a problem with streaming audio on my website. I thought I could put the MP3 file inside an MP4 container with h264 codec, so I can use **pseudo-streaming** ability of mp4 codec.

The code I'm using to convert my files is:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -y -b:a 32K -vn 1.mp4
```

Pseudo-streaming (seeking in not-loaded parts of media) now works in HTML5 player but not in any Flash media players such as JWPlayer or FlowPlayer.

I've tested my files on both Apache server with `h264` module enabled and Nginx with `mod_mp4` enabled, but without any lucks.

I tried [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box), [QTIndexSwapper](http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/) and even creating a real video file by mixing of an image loop and my audio file.

```
ffmpeg -y -i joojoo.png -i 2.mp3 -vcodec mjpeg havij.mp4
MP4Box -add havij.mp4 -isma havij_new.mp4
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to hint the file. Check out mp4box -hint